# Inkscape to convert svg to png

Tags: php, svg, inkscape

I am currently working on a PHP script that is converting SVG to png and for that purpose I am currently using the Inkscape solution.
It works like a charm but when there is a lot of visitors it is causing server load even if I am using a dedicated server with a powerful CPU.I am looking for a way to do the same job but with less load and generates images with less capacity (KBs).

Comment: add more servers, and/or optimize code, and/or switch rendering apps to one that's more efficient.

Comment: @MarcB That's what i am looking for a rendering app that is more efficient and less consumming

Comment: And asking for software recommendations is explicitly off-topic.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Are those individual, new SVG images every time? If not - implement some form of caching.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are not asking for software recommandation but for a way to speed up inkscape PNG rendering, consider changing the resolution of the output PNG. This can be done on the command line with the `-d` option.

Comment: can i change resolution and keep the same height and width?

Comment: In pixels or in a distance unit? In pixels of course not. If image is for display on screen (or print), you prescribe the scaling of the image. If the resolution for this scaling is lower than the one of the screen, pixel effects become visible.